# How can I do a post build event in sharpdevelop

Tags: post-build-event, sharpdevelop, excel-dna

I've been developping an Excel library (xll) using Excel-DNA under Visual Studio (Trial version) only because it's the only version with I've found with Post-Build event so it would pack my whole library in one file.

But now I've found out that SharpDevelop can offer the same experiance as an open source project which would be great for what I do, only I can't figure out how to get the post-build packing to work.

This is my post-build event in Visual Studio:

```
echo F | xcopy "c:\uri\to\packages\Excel-DNA.0.30.3\tools\ExcelDna64.xll" "$(TargetDir)Name-of-AddIn.xll" /C /Y
"c:\uri\to\packages\Excel-DNA.0.30.3\tools\ExcelDnaPack.exe" "$(TargetDir)Name-of-AddIn.dna" /Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined the post build in Visual Studio then it should just work in SharpDevelop. The post build command will be saved inside the project itself and MSBuild will execute it when the project is compiled.

If it does not then I would open up a command prompt and run MSBuild directly on your solution and see what if any errors are reported.

Comment: When the post-build event runs under Visual Studio I get an output (with eventually some errors), but in SharpDevelop there is absolutlly nothing. I know I can run this manually but I really would like to have SharpDevelop do it for me as I do it very often...

Comment: You should not need to run it manually. SharpDevelop will be using MSBuild pretty much the same way that Visual Studio is. It should be behaving the same as if you are running it within Visual Studio, or compiling your solution directly from the command line. You can try changing the MSBuild verbosity setting in SharpDevelop to get you more output (Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Build verbosity). Otherwise try compiling your solution from the command line to see if any errors are being reported.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to the verbose setting I found out the reason it didn't compile everything in a single file: it didn't find the .dna file.